# removing item from many css selectors

Tags: css

I have a vague memory, but can't find anything on it, about being able to use a keyword "with" or "like" to do something similar to the following.

```
using .class1{
  #a1, #a4{color:#ffffff;}
  #a2{color:#dddddd;}
  #a3{color:#eeeeee;}
}
```

instead of having to write:

```
.class1 #a1, .class #a4{color:#ffffff;}
.class2 #a2{color:#dddddd;}
.class3 #a3{color:#eeeeee;}
```

The issue is that I'm including some html/css in a page and the css is screwing up the rest of the page. So, I'd like to modify the css so it only affect the small portion, rather than the whole page. I'm doing all this programmatically on a large number of pages, so it'd be much easier to just wrap all of the new css in something like "using .class1" rather than parsing through the css and add .class1 to the beginning of every selector.

Any ideas? thanks!!

Comment: There's nothing like what you are describing that is part of CSS.  The only thing you can do is make your selectors more specific so that you only target exactly the elements you want or switch to using a CSS Preprocessor.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to achieve what you want unless you use some CSS preprocessor like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/). Here's how it would look when done using SASS:

```
.class1 {
  #a1, #a4 {
      color: #ffffff;
  }
  #a2 {
      color: #dddddd;
  }
  #a3 {
      color: #eeeeee;
   }
}
```

Reference: [little link](http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html#nesting).

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the block of included HTML in its own ID like `#overRideCSS`

Then if you ever need to over-ride specific styles, you can preface your selector with that ID:

```
#overRideCSS <other selectors> {etc...}
```

Comment: Right, in your example #overRideCSS is the same as my .class1. The problem then is that I have to parse through their css and figure out where to put #overRideCSS in each line of the css which isn't trivial. If there was some way to wrap the whole css with something like: "using #overRideCSS{" and then keep the rest of the css, it would make the process much easier.

Comment: ah, you're programatically changing their CSS? That seems overkill. Why not just add your more specific CSS after the fact (FYI, IDs are more specific that classes, hence suggesting the ID)

Comment: The problem is we're doing this with thousands of pages, each with their own css. Our site is huge, so not reasonable to change our css for this, and hand editing each of the new bits is also too time consuming.

Comment: Are you adding thousands of unique blocks of HTML? Or is it one shared chunk across thousands of pages? If the latter, then all you'd need is one extra CSS file.

Comment: all unique. looks like we'll run a script on each block of css to add the selector in. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I'm still confused as to why you need to edit the current CSS vs. just adding some extra. Maybe showing some examples of the HTML you are adding would help.